# Inserts a record in database, but does not play success code in ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My code inserts a record in database successfully, but doesn't retrieve message "Sent successfully" and doesn't redirect to any other view and doesn't clear text boxes after inserting. 
It seems as though The post method is just stopping.

Controler:

```
//GET 
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        return View();
    }

//POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactUs(string Name, string Email, string Message, string Address)
    {
        ContactusMessages contactUs = new ContactusMessages();
        contactUs.Name = Name;
        contactUs.Email = Email;
        contactUs.Phone = "---";
        contactUs.Message = Message;
        contactUs.IPAddress = Address;
        contactUs.IsSeen = false;
        contactUs.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        db.ContactusMessages.Add(contactUs);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ModelState.Clear();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeEn");

    }
```

View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ContactUs";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUserEn.cshtml";
}

<section class="body-contact">
<div class="container">
    <div class="content" id="contact-us">
        <div class="top">
            <img src="~/Content/itree-en/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        </div>

            <form id="myForm" method="post">

            <div class="right">
                <input id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" />

                <h5 id="Err_Email" style="font-weight: 100;font-size: 14px;color:#FF0000;"></h5>
                <input id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email " type="text" value="" />

                <input id="Address" name="Address" placeholder="Address" type="text" value="" />

            </div>
            <div class="left">

                <textarea cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="2"></textarea>

                <button type="submit" value="Send" class="hvr-underline-from-center" id="b">Send</button>

                <h5 id="result"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="message" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></h5>
            </div>
           </form>

          </div>
          </div>
          </section>
          <script>
            function onformsubmitProject() {
        if ($('#Name').val() != '' && $('#Email').val() != '' && $('#Address').val() != '' && $('#Message').val() != '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if ($('#Name').val() == '') { $('#Name').css("borderColor", "red"); } else { $('#Name').css("borderColor", ""); }
            if ($('#Email').val() == '') { $('#Email').css("borderColor", "red"); } else { $('#Email').css("borderColor", ""); }
            if ($('#Address').val() == '') {   $('#Address').css("borderColor", "red"); } else {  $('#Address').css("borderColor", ""); }
            if ($('#Message').val() == '') {  $('#Message').css("borderColor", "red"); } else {  $('#Message').css("borderColor", ""); }
            return false;
        }
        };
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myForm').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (!onformsubmitProject()) return false;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/HomeEn/ContactUs',
                type: 'post',
                data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function () {

                    $('#b').html('Sending .....'); // change submit button text
                    $('#result').text("");
                    $('#Name').css("borderColor", "");
                    $('#Email').css("borderColor", "");
                    $('#Address').css("borderColor", "");
                    $('#Message').css("borderColor", "");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // There is no problem with the validation
                    if (data.success) {
                        $('#b').html('Send');
                        $('#result').text("Sent successfully");
                        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
                        $('#Name').css("borderColor", "");
                        $('#Err_Email').text("");
                        $('#Address').css("borderColor", "");
                        $('#Message').css("borderColor", "");
                        $('#Email').css("borderColor", "");
                    }
                    // Problem happend during the validation, display message related to the field.
                    $.each(data.Errors, function (key, value) {
                        if (value != null) {
                            //$("#Err_" + key).html(value[value.length - 1].ErrorMessage);
                            $("#" + key).css("borderColor", "rgba(247, 5, 5, 0.53)");
                            $('#b').html('Send');
                            $('#result').text("");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Looks a bit odd. You're using an async call to get data, but the method you're calling is redirecting to an action. What's in that action?

Comment: The reason for that is because you don't have any code to retrieve the data.  Instead of just returning View() on the HttpGet method, you may need to add more code to retrieve the information.

Comment: no it doesn't go to any action , it still stand in the same page and the textboxes are full

Comment: although , the record was inserted

Comment: the button still on "sending" which in this line in javaScript code : 
                    $('#b').html('Sending .....'); // change submit button text

Comment: Is there a reason that you are binding all of those individual attributes as strings and not making them part of a model or view model?

Comment: What do you mean _doesn't redirect to any other view_? Your making an ajax call - ajax calls never redirect.

Comment: And `if (data.success) {` makes no sense - `data` is the html your returning which does not contain a property named `success` (nor does `$.each(data.Errors, function (key, value) {`

Comment: Travis Tubbs  Hdont know how can I use model in view if I use model object in action

Comment: Stephen Muecke  I mean this statement    return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeEn"); doesn't be executed

Comment: ok  
Stephen Muecke  I am still learning Ajax and java script and Jquery , what do you suggest to be Edited

Comment: @Heba, To notify someone, start the message as this one does. If you want to redirect then DO NOT use ajax. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. But you code shows no understanding of MVC and you need to go the the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics including how to pass a model to the view, include validation attributes, strongly bind to the model using the `HtmlHelper` methods and post back the model. All this can be done correctly with 1/10 of the code you have shown.

Comment: I used Ajax to show message "send successfully" when data is inserted in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood you need Ajax.Beginform . I have changed your view accordingly. Please check.

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "ContactUs";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUserEn.cshtml";
        var formId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  }
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<section class="body-contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content" id="contact-us">
            <div class="top">
                <img src="~/Content/itree-en/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                <h3>Contact Us</h3>
            </div>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContactUs", "HomeEn", new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "post",
                        OnBegin = "Begin",
                        OnFailure = "Failure",
                        OnComplete = "Complete",
                        OnSuccess = string.Format("Success(data, '{0}')", formId)
                    }, new{id = formId}))
            {
                <form id="myForm" method="post">

                    <div class="right">
                        <input id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" />

                        <h5 id="Err_Email" style="font-weight: 100;font-size: 14px;color:#FF0000;"></h5>
                        <input id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email " type="text" value="" />

                        <input id="Address" name="Address" placeholder="Address" type="text" value="" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="left">

                        <textarea cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="2"></textarea>

                        <button type="submit" value="Send" class="hvr-underline-from-center" id="b">Send</button>

                        <h5 id="result"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="message" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></h5>
                    </div>
                </form>
            }


        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function onformsubmitProject() {
        if ($('#Name').val() != '' && $('#Email').val() != '' && $('#Address').val() != '' && $('#Message').val() != '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if ($('#Name').val() == '') { $('#Name').css("borderColor", "red"); } else { $('#Name').css("borderColor", ""); }
            if ($('#Email').val() == '') { $('#Email').css("borderColor", "red"); } else { $('#Email').css("borderColor", ""); }
            if ($('#Address').val() == '') { $('#Address').css("borderColor", "red"); } else { $('#Address').css("borderColor", ""); }
            if ($('#Message').val() == '') { $('#Message').css("borderColor", "red"); } else { $('#Message').css("borderColor", ""); }
            return false;
        }
    };


    function Begin() {

        if (!onformsubmitProject()) return false;
        $('#b').html('Sending .....'); // change submit button text
        $('#result').text("");
        $('#Name').css("borderColor", "");
        $('#Email').css("borderColor", "");
        $('#Address').css("borderColor", "");
        $('#Message').css("borderColor", "");
    }
    function Success(data, formId) {
        if (data == "success") {
            $('#b').html('Send');
            $('#result').text("Sent successfully");
            document.getElementById(formId).reset();
            $('#Name').css("borderColor", "");
            $('#Err_Email').text("");
            $('#Address').css("borderColor", "");
            $('#Message').css("borderColor", "");
            $('#Email').css("borderColor", "");
        }

    }

    function Failure(data) {

    }
    function Complete(data) {

    }

</script>
```

Note that you need to add jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to work it successfully.

You Also need to change your controller a little bit. You have to send JsonResult and you will receive the corresponding result here in Javascript function.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ContactUs(string Name, string Email, string Message, string Address)
        {
            ContactusMessages contactUs = new ContactusMessages();
            contactUs.Name = Name;
            contactUs.Email = Email;
            contactUs.Phone = "---";
            contactUs.Message = Message;
            contactUs.IPAddress = Address;
            contactUs.IsSeen = false;
            contactUs.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            db.ContactusMessages.Add(contactUs);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
           // return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeEn");

        }
```

Here I returned "success" as json result. You can change it as per your requirement.

NB: I have left function Failure(data) and function Complete(data) blank intentionally. You keep your code here or if you don't need you can remove these from js as well as Ajax constructor.
I have checked and the code is working fine. Best of luck !!!!!!!

Comment: To work Ajax.BeginForm functionality we need to add the reference of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax library.If  not already installed install it from NuGet package manager.

Comment: jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js , how can I add it?? from Nuget ??

Comment: yes for NuGet package manager or package manager console. Follow the link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax.